# Parse Error with an ajax call to Google Calendar API

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to call the google calendar API. It works from the API explorer but it fails from javascript (jquery)

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/freeBusy?key="+apikey,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: {
        "timeMin": "2013-01-30T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
})
```

On the api explorer it returns an error saying that timeMax is missing (and it's ok)

```
"message": "Missing timeMax parameter."
```

The ajax calls returns instead a Parse Error, and I don't understand why

```
"message": "Parse Error"
```

Comment: Try to remove `?key="+apikey` from your url and pass it thrue `data` property.

Comment: Same error, nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Over a year later, I came across your post. I just put all my parameters in the URL like so. I use jsonp and http GET because I'm doing a simple parse of a read only calendar feed. I use moment.js to format all my times.

```
var https = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/' + calendarId + '/events?    singleEvents=true&orderBy=startTime&sortOrder=ascending&timeMin=' + moment(startMin).format() + '&timeMax=' + moment(startMax).format() + '&key=' + key;
$.ajax({
    url: https,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: "GET",
    success: function (response) {
        processFeed(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Here is a fully working URL that is giving me a read-only feed on our website. Copy and inspect it and maybe it will reveal something about the URL you are constructing. Note you must update <yourIDhere> and <yourKeyHere> https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/<yourIDhere>/events?singleEvents=true&orderBy=startTime&sortOrder=ascending&timeMin=2014-11-19T00:00:00-06:00&timeMax=2014-11-26T00:00:00-06:00&key=<yourKeyHere>

Comment: I think moment.js might be the solution. I made a fiddle to see what your time 2013-01-30T00:00:00.000Z would look like as output: [http://jsfiddle.net/Xorat/7ct93m3u/](http://jsfiddle.net/Xorat/7ct93m3u/). It appears to change the time to 2013-01-29T18:00:00-06:00

Comment: Nothing changes. Maybe the problem is with the apikey. I'll review how to gain it (it's been a long time)